# Why are fields with no frequency or oscillation in quantum electro dynamics called field?

Tags: terminology, field-theory

Yesterday i saw a video on quantum electro dynamics. It saw that there is a field everywhere, though its oscillation might be 0 or it might have no energy. Now my question is if there is no energy then how is the field there. Also is the field like thin 2D fabric one on top of other or it it a single 3D field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think of a field oscillation like a bump in a carpet. if there is no bump, the carpet is still there; similarly, even if there are no field excitations, the field still exists.